# D6 to D8 migrate new content

Tags: migrations

I did a D6 to D8 migration in 10/2015 and I recreated the blocks and views not migrated.  But in the mean time 6 month later my D6 original site has been getting more content.

What is the best way to bring all of that content from the last 6 month from my D6 to my migrated D8?

Answer (score 0):

You should use migrate module, it's in drupal8's core.

You can define migrations for blocks, nodes, comments, users ... and launch then when you need.

You can select "update" option to syncronize imported content on your new site with changed content on old site.

Here's the offical doc of migrate:
https://www.drupal.org/migrate

Comment: Thanks, I look at this link I am having getting my head around this.

Answer (score 0):

@user551799 - presumably you used either the UI or the drush migrate-upgrade command provided by [migrate_upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade), correct? As long as you haven't upgraded your D8 site to the 8.1.x branch, you should be able to simply run it again, and it will import your content on top of the old content.

Comment: My migrated d6.38 to d8.1.1, I remigrated and brought a bunch of records.  There errors but it completed. It is big site and after migrations the number of nodes is different.  The live site DB has 7417 nodes.  The first remigrated DB has 7326 nodes.  I guess some of the errors probably cause the missing nodes in the remigrated DB.  I do not see a difference up to know but I notice that in my primary links menu one of the choices shows only if I am an admin:

Comment: you can see the problem with the menu after the remigration here: [link](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207592/d6-to-d8-remigrate-1-of-8-menu-choices-not-displaying-for-anonymous)

Comment: FYI - I did the whole remigration and it found 162 errors before it crashed. I started with 6915 nodes and I have now 7327 nodes but the live site has 7417.  The remigration crashed but the site does not seem be negative affected this time and the menus are good.  Thanks!!