# Why is 1 of 8 menu choices not displaying for anonymous users?

Tags: 8, navigation

I have a migrated a Drupal 6 site to Drupal 8, but in order to update the content
I remigrated it. In my Primary link menu I have 8 menus, but
now one of then is shown only to the administrator user.

```
About Board of  Water  Construction Business Finance Community News &
 us   Directors Supply Facilities   Opps     Invest  Outreach  Publications
```

Anonymous users see the following.

```
About Water  Construction Business Finance Community News &
 us   Supply Facilities   Opps     Invest  Outreach  Publications
```

This is something that was not happening when I did my first migration.

I am using [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish).

What happened? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the permission of whatever "Board of Directors" links to (a node, a view, something else?). To ensure anonymous have permission to access it (also).

Comment: Wow, I discovered that the node that this link pointed to had disappeared during the remigration, but it would display for the admin but not for anonymous users.  it looks like I have to recreate the nodes that the menu and submenus pointed to. - Thanks!!

Comment: @user551799 : merci for the "thanks" ... It sounds like my answer helped somehow. Are you familiar with what's written [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?